# Show login screen if user not logged in

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboardsegue

I have an Xcode project and I have my main view controller load, and then in `viewDidLoad` I use an if statement to check if the user is logged in and if they are not in `viewDidLoad` I do this

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showLogin" sender:self];
```

But there is a lag between so that the main view controller is shown for about 1 second and it looks weird and annoying how can I have it so that it goes staring from the splash screen to the login, if the user is not logged in?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a loading view over maincontrollerview and hide it when finish check the login.

Here a screen shot for make more clean what I intend in the comment:

[image]

Comment: would I add this loading view in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`?

Comment: I think is better in viewDidLoad if you don't use story board. If you use storyboard drag a view over all, connect it to viewController and hide it when user are logged.

Comment: I use storyboard and I have a table view already in my main view and the view doesn't hide it?

Comment: If you use table view in a view controller add the  "loading view" after table view, for decide if place view in front or back, in botton left of storyboard open "Document Outline".